# How to write Jasmine spec for jQuery click event with handler

Tags: jquery, jasmine

Below is a code sample for the method for which I am struggling to write a spec. How do I call below event from example-spec.js?

```
$('.send-me').on('click', 'a.cloth-tile.active', function(event) {
  // write code here
}
```

Currently I am writing `$(.send-me).click()` but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

The event is bound to `a.cloth-tile.active`, so that's where you need to raise the event. You also need to wrap the selector string in quotes:

```
$('a.cloth-tile.active').click()
```

Note that this will raise the event on *all* of those elements in the DOM. If you want to target a specific one use its index.